# Blurry font when connecting MBP Mid-2012, Retina to an HPes 27" display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My MBP (Mid 2012, Retina) running El Capitan is now connected to an external [HP Display](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/hp-hp-27-fhd-7ms-gtg-ips-led-monitor-27es-black-27es/10448939.aspx?path=9355394b033e283b997faecf375440cben02) via an HDMI cable.
It all works fine, but the fonts on the HP are not as smooth as the MBP. Now, I get that Retina is quite superior so I may immediately catch abnormalities in an external display - but I assure you, that's not the case.

The HP font is significantly rough on the edges, contributing to a blurry font (and a string of headaches).
I called HP, and they tried to get me to buy their $67 paid support to give me the "drivers" for the monitor that I know they don't have.

Either I need to get an easy fix here, or I call Apple, OR you folks can be kind enough to refer me to any other affordable and sleek looking external display at [BestBuy](http://bestbuy.ca) or Amazon.ca

I still have a return policy on hand with this bestbuy, so I may be able to exchange it for a display that doesn't have these silly issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How are you connecting to the display?

I've used screens in the past (a particular model dell springs to mind) which applied sharpening to the HDMI input by default, resulting in "crunchy-looking" type. That could be worth checking.

It's also fair to say that the MacOS doesn't always handle transitioning windows from retina to non-retina screens -- I've seen plenty of instances where the windows fonts in FCPX become extra-jagged until some magic combination of moving the window from screen to screen and/or rebooting the mac solves the issue. That's with a mix of screens, including the thunderbolt display.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I'm connecting via HDMI, and I swapped the ports too.. nada :(